# Vue js, how to get callback from emit

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

So Im made an $emit to an event bus in other conponent,  where the component run a function 'save' from $on.

Is there a way to send a callback to emit showing that the 'save' function is made succesfully?

Im a bit new to vue.  Thanx for all help

Comment: you can pass the state to the component by using a data variable and a watcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to emit a second event using the EventBus to show that the save function was successful. Or, as @samayo mentioned, you could use state (Vuex). Read more about managing state with Vuex [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

Comment: he can do it without a second eventbus ... just one is enough, but he has to watch a variable from vue instance ... it's a little complicated but vuex is a better choice

Comment: I didn't say a second eventbus...just a second event :)

Comment: Well,  i like both answer,  emitting second event or using vuex.  Thanks guys,  ill try both method and see which suits my needs